# What is the difference between ... and : in Pytorch tensors and numpy indexing

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor

I am trying to get used to Pytorch indexing. However I couldn't understand the difference between tensor[:,-1] (which should print the last column) and tensor[...,-1] which is printing different output (output2)

```
import torch
tensor = torch.rand([3,3,3,3])
print('Output1')
print(tensor[:,-1])
print('Output2')
print(tensor[...,-1])
```

Comment: With `rand` and the same 3 dimensions you can't tell.  But with `np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)` you should be able identify the difference. `x[:,-1]` does not print the last "column", it indexes the 2nd dimension, which in a 4d array is not usually called a "column".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the following indices are equivalent

```
tensor[:, -1] == tensor[:, -1, :, :]
tensor[..., -1] == tensor[:, :, :, -1]
```